# How can I plot markers on my map after their locations are retrieved from my database?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using google maps api to plot a few markers on the map based on locations that I retrieve from Firebase database. This works fine when I retrieve the data from database in a different activity and pass them by intents but when I retrieve the data in this activity, it's plotting a blank map.
My Database:

```
report
 -KZPjqQOP086w1t6dOUY
 -KZZnf5c4QdNnLHMgfrG
 -KZ_90sfB2QTLtmcSvHW
 -KZ_9SnWuu_wDBStHAD6
 -KZ_9VGt5UKw9W7Hzdhp
      currentstatus: "still_there"
      description: "new"
      img: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMMAAAEECAIAAAAahxdFAAA..."
      latitude: "37.3400953"
      longitude: "-121.8955277"
      severity: "Minor"
      size: "Extra Large"
      street: "300-364 Coleman Avenue"
      timeNdate: "Wed Dec 21 22:13:28 PST 2016"
```

I tried to debug this and it looks like it is plotting the map before it retrieves the data. How can I correct this so it plots them right?

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public String latReport;
    public String longiReport;
    public String streetReport;
    public String repClicked;

    private GoogleMap Mmap;

    String SLat;
    String SLong;
    String gmail;
    String who;
    String Data;
    HashMap<Marker, String> Imagemap = new HashMap<>();
    // ArrayList<Report> reportArrayList;
    ArrayList<String> Lat;
    ArrayList<String> Lng;
    ArrayList<String> Street = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> emailid = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> size = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> severity = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> img = new ArrayList<>();
    //ArrayList<String> Street = new ArrayList<>();
    Query queryRef;
    int i;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    DatabaseReference dRef;

    ArrayList<Report> reportArrayList;

    ArrayAdapter<Report> arrayAdapter;

    Report value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        who = intent.getStringExtra("Off");
        String markerimage;
        Lat = new ArrayList<>();
        dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        reportArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRef = dRef.child("report");
        Query qRef;
        qRef = mRef.orderByChild("emailId");


        qRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report.class);

                Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded: "+value.getEmailId());
                Log.i(TAG, "Locaton: "+value.getLatitude());
                Log.i(TAG, "Locaton: "+value.getLongitude());
                reportArrayList.add(value);
                Lat.add(value.getLatitude());
                Lng.add(value.getLatitude());
              }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        for (i = 0; i < Lat.size(); i++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded: "+Lat.get(i));
            latReport = reportArrayList.get(i).getLatitude();
            longiReport = reportArrayList.get(i).getLongitude();
            streetReport = reportArrayList.get(i).getStreet();



            double number = Double.parseDouble(latReport);
            double number2 = Double.parseDouble(longiReport);

            Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(number, number2))
                    .title(streetReport));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(number, number2), 15));
            Mmap = map;
            String cimage = img.get(i);
            Imagemap.put(marker,cimage);
        }
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String markerimage = Imagemap.get(marker);
                Intent intentnew = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OfficialDetail.class);
                for (int iter = 0; iter < Lat.size(); iter++) {
                   if (markerimage.equals(img.get(iter)))
                    {
                        Data = Street.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("street_of", Data);
                        Data = Lat.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("lat_of", Data);
                        Data = Lng.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("long_of", Data);
                        Data = description.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("lat_of", Data);
                        Data = size.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("size_of", Data);
                        Data = severity.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("severity_of", Data);
                        Data = img.get(iter);
                        intentnew.putExtra("img_of", Data);
                        if(who=="User")
                        intentnew.putExtra("Off","User");
                        else
                        intentnew.putExtra("Off","Off");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                startActivity(intentnew);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit: I had posted code where I was just checking if the code was being retrieved. This is the latest code. I populated the Lat Array list after I retrieve from the database**
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: where you getting the Lat values

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I had deleted Lat to check if it was getting populated. I corrected it now. :)

Comment: You create Lat list, add a listener and then do    for (i = 0; i < Lat.size(); i++) {... } Quite obviously Lat will be empty, given that the listener fires not until the event comes. (Actually it wouldn't come unless you exit UI thread to let the system process pending events). This is why you get a blank hash map.

Comment: @cyanide Thank you, cyanide. I figured that might be it but I can't figure out how to correct it. Should I use a different Listener?